JSON data doesn't apprear on Postman
I try to post some data on the website, and it runs perfectly when I run on Pycharm. But when I try on Postman it still gets OK(200) but I don't get my JSON data. Here is my code
import requests
import json

with open('input.json','r') as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)

r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get", data=file_data)

print(r.text)


I want to double-check that my data has been posted on both sides.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Shouldn't you be using request.post(..)?

This code works for me. I just replaced null to None:
import requests

data = {
        "args": {},
        "data": "",
        "files": {},
        "form": {
        "a": "1",
        "id": "123",
        "model": "a12",
        "name": "John",
        "number": "456",
        "status": "OK"
    },
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Length": "51",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.32.3",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-66d82479-64115df475c1d2fc14803b3c"
    },
    "json": None, 
    "origin": "117.0.114.106", 
    "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get", data=data)

print(r.text)

